# My python program doesn't quit, keeps running loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm writing a short program where users pick otions, I wrote a function (Yes/No) for the user to pick wether to return to home or quit program, when the user picks "No", the program is supposed to display a goodbye! message and quit but the loop seems to display the goodbye message but still prompting the user if they want to quit or not.

This is my function

```
def exit_home():
    while True:
            user = input("home or exit? (Yes/No)").lower()
            if user == "yes":
                main()
            elif choice == "no":
                print(quit)
                quit()
                print("Bye! ")
                continue
            else:
                break
                print("enter a valid input (Yes or No)")
```

And I get the result below

```
home or exit? (Yes/No)no
<IPython.core.autocall.ZMQExitAutocall object at 0x7fa9c096df10>
Bye! 

home or exit? (Yes/No)
```

Also if there's a neater way of let user exit the program without printing the <IPython.core blah blah blah> I would appreciate the sugesstion.

Thanks

Comment: you're using `user` as the parameter but you've got `elif choice == 'no'`...

Comment: Because that is how you coded it.  You have `continue` and `break` the wrong way around.  Moreover this has a code-smell about it.  Where is `exit_home()` called from?  Recursion is not iteration, and it looks likely that you are recursively calling `main()` which is a really bad idea.

Comment: You must have overridden *quit()* otherwise your program would have terminated and hence 'Bye!' would never have been emitted. What do you think a call to *print()* is going to do after *break*?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your code:

1. Remove `print(quit)` to get rid of
   `<IPython.core.autocall.ZMQExitAutocall object at 0x7fa9c096df10>`
2. Use `return` to break the loop instead of `continue`
3. `print` after `break` doesn't make sense because `print` will never be executed
4. `break` doesn't make sense because it breaks the loop, but you want to get into another interation

Corrected code:

```
while True:
    action = input("home or exit? (Yes/No) ").lower()
    if action == "yes":
        print("call main function...")
    elif action == "no":
        print("Bye! ")
        break
    else:
        print("enter a valid input (Yes or No)")
```

Sample output:

```
home or exit? (Yes/No) yes
call main function...
home or exit? (Yes/No) maybe
enter a valid input (Yes or No)
home or exit? (Yes/No) no
Bye!
```

Answer (score 0):

`<IPython.core.autocall.ZMQExitAutocall object at 0x7fa9c096df10>` was shown because you printed out the function.

Just this should work.

```
import sys

elif choice == "no":
     print("Bye! ")
     sys.exit()
```